# How to find the previous element height using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which is defined like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>First</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' style='widht:200px; height:100px;' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class='but'></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Second</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select style='widht:100px; height:150px;'>
                <option>one</one>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class='but'></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' style='widht:200px; height:100px;' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class='but'></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Third</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea style='widht:500px; height:200px;'></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class='but'></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then on button click I want to get the height of the previous control. So I wrote this code:

```
 $(".but").live('click',function(){
     alert($(this).prev().css('width'));
     alert($(this).prev().css('height'));
 });
```

But the alert's are showing the values as undefined. How can I solve this?

Comment: you've spelt width wrong in your html FYI. `</button ..`  is also incorrect.

Comment: $(this).prev().height(); maybe ?

Comment: </button class='but'></button>
should be 
<button class='but'></button>

Comment: hey sorry for the mistakes. I changed that.

Comment: jquery.live() is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: @Naidu _`hey sorry for the mistakes. I changed that`_ I am unable to see. i can still see `</button> and widht`

Comment: @Naidu $('.but') is the first element so it does not have any previous element so can you exactly tell of which element you want the heiht and width

Comment: It will be easier if you can add a class to previous elements like select, textarea, input etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var input = $(this).parent().prev().find("input");
if(input) { // You have a select, so this won't be found in all circumstances
    alert(input.css('width'));
    alert(input.css('height'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use real `width()` to get real width of an element instead of width defined in css (`.css('width')`). The same applies for height:

```
$(".but").live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).prev().width());
    alert($(this).prev().height());
});
```

Comment: Because there is no previous element inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is no previous target of your buttons.

If you want the TD height, you should call .parent() instead.

And please, pay attention to your HTML !

EDIT: Fiddle updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/jVsRW/4/

```
$(".but").on('click', function() {
    // Of course display null for the first button that do not have a previous form element.
    alert($(this).closest('tr').prev().find('input, select, textarea').height());
});
```

Comment: It's depending of the value that you need to get, which one is it ?

Comment: `$(this).prev().height()` is displaying `null`

Comment: Yeah of course, I would to show you the difference between prev() and parent().

<td><button class='but'></button><td>

You don't have a previous element before your button in the same container (<td>), so prev() is not an element.

Instead of parent(), that will be the container (<td>, here).

Comment: ok but i don't want the parent height i want only element height. The height is different for those two

Comment: Okay I didn't understand this. So you could try: $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('input, select, textarea').height(). I've updated my fiddle ! http://jsfiddle.net/jVsRW/4/

Answer (score 0):

you can try:  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7b37/)

```
$(".but").live('click',function(){
     alert($(this).closest("tr").find('input').css('width')); 
     // OR
     //alert($(this).closest("tr").find('select').css('width'));     
});
```